# Why my ipynb files are downloaded as txt file in Google Colab

Tags: google-colaboratory

This seems wierd, but my Google Colab was working fine until the last two days the Download .ipynb option is not downloading .ipynb files but rather txt files. I have to rename the file to ipynb and the notebooks are working fine. Anybody have faced such issues with Colab?

Comment: `.ipynb` are JSON files which are [human-readable text files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON).

Comment: @Parfait I used to get the files as ipynb files itself, not as JSON files.

Comment: Yeah, i am facing the same issue now. We may can get this problem when we rename the json file to ipynb in local system and upload it to collab and after some changes in collab, if we try downloading the ipynb from collab, it will be downloaded as text document.

Comment: @Bhargavchowdary, true how did you solve the problem, for me now after a perios of time, it turned out to be working as usual

Answer (score 1):

facing same problem while downloading kaggle file as .txt rather than ipynb file i just Re-named file name as ipynb then after got it.

Comment: Please format your answer for better readability.

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution to this is, **while saving to local system**,by default colab may give as json or text file. But we can **change it to All files** and add **.ipynb as suffix to the file name**